# Skip composer PHP requirement

Tags: php, composer-php, versioning

We are using PHPCI and composer. The server which runs PHPCI is on PHP 5.3.

For a project we added the Facebook PHP SDK, using composer. It requires PHP 5.4.
Composer gets triggered by PHPCI and get executed. But because the CI server just got PHP 5.3 composer failed with the error message:

```
facebook/php-sdk-v4 4.0.9 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
```

This let fail my build in PHPCI, of course.

Is there a possibility to skip this requirement? Maybe by adding an option to composer.json? Or a parameter to composer.phar call?

Answer (score 438, accepted):

I've found the option:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Ignore platform requirements (php & ext- packages).

---

#### Alternative: Specify your projects' PHP version

You can skip the platform checks by configuring `composer.json#/config/platform/php` with the PHP version to use.

Composer will fetch packages based on that configured PHP version then.

So when you need to tell Composer the PHP version for your projects dependencies, you can (and should) specify the PHP version if different than the PHP version you execute `composer` with in your `composer.json` project configuration file (AKA root package):

```
{
    "config": {
       "platform": {
           "php": "5.6.6"
       }
    }
}
```

Here PHP 5.6.6 version is exemplary, it could be `8.0.4` or any other PHP version.

This also documents the target (platform) PHP configuration. Additionally installed PHP extensions and library versions can be specified.

Compare: [*Config: platform - Composer documentation*](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform)

Comment: How can i ignore private repository. Some package require private repo.

Comment: Awesome. It's useful when php cli is not reflecting a version change yet.

Comment: In Composer 2 there is a new command, which can get used: https://php.watch/articles/composer-ignore-platform-req

Comment: You can also use `--ignore-platform-reqs=php` if you want to make sure it is only ignoring the php version requirement.

Comment: Actually it's `--ignore-platform-req php` (singular) and only works till Composer 2.

Comment: Install as many packages as you can first. Then install remaining packages while ignoring platform requirements.

Answer (score 30):

For many commands, you can tell composer to bypass php version check, with parameter "`--ignore-platform-reqs`":

```
composer COMMAND --ignore-platform-reqs
```

this will bypass php version specification.

Be aware that the software may work or not: php version specification is there because somewhere in the code is needed at least the specified php version, so if you use that code the software will break.

Comment: `--ignore-platform-reqs` is not for all commands available, as your answer implies.

Answer (score -15):

If anything requires a specific version of PHP, it won't run in a lower version of PHP. You will properbly still recieve errors when bypassing the PHP requirement.

Btw, PHP 5.3 is no longer maintained, I would strongly recommend updating the PHPCI server.

Comment: First I would like to know how to bypass the PHP requirement.

Comment: You can't and you won't as the code won't work in a lower php version

Comment: It will. Just the CI server got the low PHP version. The server which contains the facebook SDK runs on PHP 5.4. It is just about the ci server, which packs everything to a nice deployable zip file.

Comment: Although PHP 5.3 is no longer maintained by the core PHP developers, some flavours of Linux still support it and will do for a while yet.  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ships with 5.3 and is supported until April 2017 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS).  Moving to 14.04 is the best upgrade path but there are breaking changes which require an amount of work to fix (Apache 2.4, php-fpm etc). Hence a lot of the internet still using 5.3.x.

Comment: true unfortunately 99% of packages even the well supported ones don't have the proper requirements. It's more a indicator of what the developer is using than anything else.

Comment: "it won't run in a lower version of PHP". The statement is simply no true. The package that OP is trying to install might run just fine.  Perhaps this should have been a comment.