# Composer and PHP versions, ignoring PHP version on Composer install, a bad idea?

Tags: php, composer-php

After PHP being updated on our server (Centos 5.11) to be > v5.3.2, I want to get Composer installed like I have in my other environments.

The [Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) state that "Composer requires PHP 5.3.2+ to run". I have PHP 5.4.45. Still, when trying

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

It exits with the warning

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/versions): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in - on line 762
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in - on line 508
None of the 0 stable version(s) of Composer matches your PHP version (5.4.45 / ID: 50445)
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165101/skip-composer-php-requirement) which deals with ignoring system requirements when installing Composer.

Is this something that could be done or is it a somewhat scary/thoughtless thing to do? And, are there other versions ("unstable" or otherwise) of Composer that I could use? Or perhaps PHP should be updated again -> 5.6.x?

Thanks for any tips and help!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but yes, you should upgrade PHP further. [PHP 5.4 stopped receiving security updates in September, 2015 and PHP 5.5 stopped receiving them in July, 2016. PHP 5.6 and 7.0 will receive security updates until roughly the end of 2018.](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: looks like it is ipv6 issue. after disable ipv6 the installer was was forced to use ipv4 for the address resolution and all went fine.

Answer (score 3):

I changed from https to http,

```
curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Then was able to install

Answer (score 2):

It's not a matter of your PHP version, but a connectivity issue.

You have 3 messages (2 warnings and one composer's info), which tell you the whole story.

(1st warning) Composer's installer couldn't fetch list of Composer's list of versions **due to connection timeout**, so (2nd warning) it didn't have a list to iterate over and match Composer's version suitable for your PHP version, which implied that (3rd message) no version of composer was found.

The root problem is the first warning. This line

```
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/versions);
```

didn't work. And that's your issue.

It's hard to tell you exact solution basing of provided information.

Comment: Indeed it is. Thank you for pointing it out. This seems harder to do anything about though, as "curling" something like example.com does return the expected result, albeit very slowly. A problem with composer.org perhaps? Or curl timing out prematurely?

Comment: It may be somthing with SSL. Did you try to execute only that `file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/versions);` in a test file?

Comment: Yes, it does return the same data as you can see [here](https://getcomposer.org/versions). Although the first few times I tested it, it did not work, claiming "No such file or directory". But it is now consistent. Something seems fishy. Could it be a syntax error? There are no quotes surrounding the url parameter.. But that could be a result of the terminal output. I must dig deeper

Comment: line 507 `$versions = json_decode($httpClient->get($uriScheme . '://getcomposer.org/versions'), true);` from [the installer on GitHub](https://github.com/composer/getcomposer.org/blob/master/web/installer) is the culprit, but there can't really be anything wrong there. Has to be something on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be proxy problems. Deleting the **https_proxy** and **http_proxy** environment vars worked for me (Windows 10). And then installing it, set proxy in blank. It should work as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

To delete variables in the current cmd instance, do this:

```
set http_proxy=
set https_proxy=
```

or (even better):

```
set "http_proxy="
set "https_proxy="
```

To delete variables for future cmd instances, do this:

```
setx http_proxy ""
setx https_proxy ""
```