# The Composer installer script was not successful [exit code 1]

Tags: laravel

Please, I need some ideas to solve this problem

The Composer installer script was not successful [exit code 1].

Your proxy settings may be causing this error.

Script Output:
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: It is saying that the machine you are running composer out of cannot connect to `https://getcomposer.org` to get that file. Are you running composer from your local machine? Maybe your IP is banned by composer

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989893/composer-and-php-versions-ignoring-php-version-on-composer-install-a-bad-idea) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

just to share my experienced on this issue on composer error # 1.

What I did was to get rid all composer inside the registry editor. It solved my problem.